# Almacenar state de dataTables diferenciando por el id del nodo seleccionado

Tags: datatables, local-storage

Intento almacenar el estado de un datatables que se carga en un jsTree, los registros del datatable dependen del nodo seleccionado, y en base al id del nodo es el nombre de la entrada en el localStorage. Se estan creando las entradas basadas en el id del nodo correctamente, pero además se crea otra entrada que toma los valores del ultimo estado almacenado, bajo la clave DataTables_tablaDatos_/app_dev.php ( es decir, basada en el id de la tabla), y al parecer este es el localstorage que se lee, por tanto al seleccionar otro nodo, se lee el estado del ultimo datatables y no el estado que tiene el id del nodo seleccionado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En la imagen se puede ver como el primer storage, coincide con el seleccionado.

Este es el codigo simplificado del datatables:

```
var _tablaDatosElement = $('#tablaDatos');
        var _dtAPI = $(_tablaDatosElement).DataTable({
            // configuracion del datatables
            "stateSave": true,
        }).on('stateSaveParams.dt', function (e, settings, data) {
            localStorage.setItem('DT_embcmf' + _tablaDatosElement.data('cmf'), JSON.stringify(data));
        }).on('stateLoadParams.dt', function (e, settings, data) {
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('DT_embcmf' + _tablaDatosElement.data('cmf')));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución es algo sencilla, en la propia definición del datatables, sobreescribí las funciones `stateLoadCallback` y `stateSaveCallback`, quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
 var _dtAPI = $(_tablaDatosElement).DataTable({
                    // definicion del datatables......
                    "stateSave": true,
                    "stateSaveCallback": function (settings, data) {
                        try {
                            localStorage.setItem('DTembcmf' + _tablaDatosElement.data('cmf'), JSON.stringify(data));
                        } catch (e) {
                        }
                    },
                    "stateLoadCallback": function (settings) {
                        try {
                            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('DTembcmf' + _tablaDatosElement.data('cmf')));
                        } catch (e) {
                        }
                    }
                });
```